# Is it feasible to lift a human off the ground with a suit of fans?

Tags: forces, gravity, lift

[image: XKCD: Rocket Packs]

So, we live in a world that is technologically developed enough where it is reasonably within reach to attach small rockets to someone/something to lift it off the ground.

One serious problem we encounter with this is damage to the surrounding environment. Even if you manage to protect yourself, your "rockets" could cause damage to the surrounding objects and terrain (since it is shooting fire after all.)

**My question is this:** is it possible to use enough small sources of lift, say, a suit of fans, spread out over a human body, to lift the human without causing damage to the environment or the human. Assume for the purposes of this question that these fans can be pivoted and controlled to point in any direction and remain there using a perfect control system, we're just worried about the physics of lift here.

I am also open to other sources of lift, but the objective would be to have something that will not hurt anyone or anything (too much. )

Comment: Since this question seems to be about "the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem" (e.g. the last sentence of the post) it might be best on http://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When I read the title, I thought you were asking about some rock star crowd-surfing.

Answer (score 2):

Lift is a result of transfer of momentum to the air. If you can move a mass $m$ per unit time, and accelerate it by $\Delta v$, the force will be $m\Delta v$. Now when you have a rocket, you have the fuel "already there" and the goal is to accelerate it to the highest velocity to make thrust. The result is a very hot stream of air, and the need for calf guards etc. Note that this is inefficient, since the power goes as $\frac12 m v^2 = \frac12 F v$. For a given force, the higher the velocity, the higher the power. The solution is to use more mass, and less velocity.

That's what happens at the other extreme - the [winner of the Sikorsky challenge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syJq10EQkog) was a human-powered quadcopter with a span of about 55 m:

[image]
 Moving a lot of air very slowly would meet the goal you had in mind - it's energy efficient (can be human powered) and the air flows slowly enough not to do any damage. On the other hand, the structure is massive and it will be hard to maneuver.

Unfortunately, just running a fan faster won't help you - the air arriving at the "input surface" of the fan is pushed by atmospheric pressure, and this limits the amount of air (mass) that can be moved. Therefore after a certain point, a faster fan doesn't really increase $m$, it only increases $v$. Meaning it uses a lot more power for a little bit of thrust.

Answer (score 0):

lift is achieved when you push down on the air with a force equal to(hovering) or greater than your weight this means that you can In theory create the system of fans that you want in fact these machines have already been created tested and they do work but the main problem is flight time and a system of fans addresses that problem more efficiently than a rocket propulsion system since by the time you have enough rocket fuel to carry you and enough fuel to carry that fuel ...you'll end up with a huge rocket and only minutes of flight time